# Google maps in iOS doesn't show multiple pins

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK in iOS app.I am stuck at plotting multiple pins on map.This is how I am trying to plot the pins.And I used the exact same approach to show multiple pins using MapKit which worked fine.But no success with google Maps.

```
-(void)plotMembersOnMap
{

  for (NSMutableDictionary *obj in self.jsonDictionary)
  {
    membersDict = [obj objectForKey:@"members"];

    NSLog(@"Count member %d",[membersDict count]);  // shows count
    for (NSDictionary *obj in membersDict)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
        NSString *latitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lat"];
        NSString *longitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lng"];

        double latitude = [latitudeString doubleValue];
        double longitude = [longitudeString doubleValue];

        center.latitude =latitude;
        center.longitude = longitude;

        NSString *userName = [obj objectForKey:@"pseudo"];
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.map = mapView_;
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude, center.longitude);
        customGoogleCallout.callOutTitleLabel.text = @"Member";
        customGoogleCallout.callOutUserName.text = userName;
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_membre.png"];


        }
  }

}
```

Comment: did U got ur answer.?

Answer (score 1):

just try to add lat and lon to an array then supply the marker.position.
have some loop for i and position is object at index[i].

Comment: But, latitude and longitude are double values

Comment: Actually I am stuck with the same error, here stackoverflow.com/questions/20944919/google-maps-in-ios-doesnt-show-multiple-pins/20945358?noredirect=1#comment31459139_20945358

Comment: my problenm is, I could able to print the dictionary] values in my log, but it is not getting displayed in my map

Comment: Could U please help me with that, @ Abhijit Chaudhar

Comment: @chandru check the answer to your question..and let me know.. can u also delete unwanted comments on this question

Answer (score 1):

this might help...

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = { [[obj objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue] , [[obj    objectForKey:@"lon"] floatValue] };
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:center];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
 NSArray *latitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lat"];
 NSArray *longitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

Instead of

```
 NSString *latitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lat"];
 NSString *longitudeString = [obj objectForKey:@"lng"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because it's plotting the latest coordinate you assign to `center`. You should make new instance so the previous value will not replaced.